# Python pip is not working

Tags: python, pip, six

I am using Python 3.4 on Windows 7.

I need to install the `six` module, I have pip installed on my C.

The problem is, whenever I type `pip` on my `cmd` nothing happens.
I made sure that my environment variables are set correctly but I am still facing the problem.

Comment: No, it is not showing anything.

Comment: What do you mean about *I have pip installed on my **C*** ?

Comment: He means on his `C:` drive, almost certainly.

Comment: I turned out that uninstalling python and reinstalling it is the best way to solve this mystery, thank you guys for helping as possible

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the pip executable to your path.

Show us your path variable, you can see it by typing this at a cmd prompt:

```
echo %PATH%
```

Do you know where pip is actually installed? On my Windows VM it's here:

```
c:\Python34\Scripts\pip.exe
```

That would mean you need `C:\Python34\Scripts` in your path.

Comment: I added this path to my environment variables

Answer (score 0):

Just download this file https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py and then run `python get-pip.py`.

Comment: He claims it's already installed. Also, I don't believe that script modifies your system path on windows, but I could be wrong. Unless he installed python from source, pip is included with python 3.4.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, to know my pip version, I have to do it as follows

```
py -m pip --version
```